# Use server-name in ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, errordocument

Trying to do this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://%{SERVER_NAME}/harper/error.html
```

I cannot put a hardcoded server name, and I tried to use this variable (which is working fine for RewriteRule, but not for ErrorDocument).

The point of this is, I want every 403 or 404 to go to /harper/error.html and it will give 302 response code. I don't want to use the code below since it won't give me 302 response. Any idea to achieve this?

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /harper/error.html
```

Comment: %{SERVER_NAME} variable is part of mod_rewrite, you cant use it in ErrorDocument.

Comment: @starkeen ah :S and there's no way to do something similar like that in ErrorDocument ?

Comment: Wouldn't it better to send right status `404/403` to clients rather than 302 for these errors?